# how to modify collection classes provided by EF after associating one class to another?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, collections, associations

I'm new to MVC & EF. I'm developing the MVC project with model first approach. In my project i have different entities like-customer,employee,product,etc. and i created association between them like 1 to many in customer-employee like this. and after creating this association; it is generating navigation property in customer entity i.e, Employees (collection object) for employee entity.

I want to modify this collection class and i want to add some more methods on it. Is it possible? How to do this if possible?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property is generated with `ICollection<Employee>` type. You can in theory create your own class implementing this interface and initialize the property for example in `Employee` constructor but the property will still expose the interface. Changing return type of the property requires change in class generator (you should use T4 template which would make this easy task). By changing property's return type to your collection you can lose some EF functionality.